# Is there a name for this property among variables?

Tags: functions, terminology, convex-analysis

I have a convex function of four variables, $f(w,x,y,z)$, which when solving for the symbolic arg min of one variable assuming the other three are known I got something similar to the following.
(Formulas were more complicated, showing simpler cases for illustration)

1. $\hat{w}= xy/z$
2. $\hat{x}= wz/y$
3. $\hat{y}= -z + wx$
4. $\hat{z}= -y + wx$

Notice that the $\{w,x\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ pair have a "symmetry". (1) and (2) can be re-arranged for the other variable and the new answer will still be correct, similarly for (3) and (4). However,  solving for $z$ from (1), for example, produces an incorrect answer for $\hat{z}$. Likewise for other combinations.

Is there a term for this property between the $\{w,x\}$ and $\{y,z\}$ variables?

Comment: What is ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}*$?

Comment: Regular multiplication. I've since edited it to avoid confusion.